# Reusing external functions with different argument names in OpenMDAO

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to generate an MDAO problem from an external specification. This requires the automated creation of groups, disciplines and variables. I would like to reuse some analytical functions, but with different arguments. I have to assume that the names of these arguments can differ between reused instances, therefore I am looking for a way to formulate analytical functions without the necessary consistency between the keys in the function's dictionary-style inputs/outputs parameters and the discipline input and output variables.

Is it possible (if so, how?) to employ one of the following reusable functions `MyReusableFunction` / `MyReusableFunctionAlt` in the following example?

```
import openmdao.api as om

### External information

# I can choose the format of disciplinary functions. Some alternatives:
def MyNonReusableFunction1(inputs, outputs): # <- The way it works
    # I have to use keys 'A', 'B', 'C' here
    outputs['C'] = inputs['A']*inputs['B']

def MyNonReusableFunction2(inputs, outputs): # <- The way it works
    # I have to use keys 'D', 'E', 'F' here
    outputs['F'] = inputs['D']*inputs['E']

def MyReusableFunction(x, y): # <- The way I want it to work
    return x*y

def MyReusableFunctionAlt(inputs, outputs): # <- This would also be fine
    outputs['z'] = inputs['x']*inputs['y']

# Given structure of the problem
disciplines = {
    'D1': {
        'inputs': ['A', 'B'],
        'outputs': ['C'],
        'function': MyReusableFunction}, # <- instead of MyNonReusableFunction1
    'D2': {
        'inputs': ['D', 'E'],
        'outputs': ['F'],
        'function': MyReusableFunction}, # <- instead of MyNonReusableFunction2
}

connections = [('D2.F', 'D1.B')]

### My script starts here

problem = om.Problem()

for disc_name, disc_data in disciplines.items():
    discipine = om.ExplicitComponent()
    discipline.compute = disc_data['function']

    for param_in in disc_data['inputs']:
        discipline.add_input(param_in, 1)
        
    for param_out in disc_data['outputs']:
        discipline.add_output(param_out, 1)

    problem.add_subsystem(disc_name, discipline)

for connection in connections:
    problem.connect(connection[0], connection[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a use case for user-defined function registration in ExecComps.  This is a brand new feature.

http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/exec_comp.html#registering-user-functions

An example of its use is here:

http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/building_blocks/components/exec_comp.html#execcomp-example-user-function-registration

This will handle derivatives for you, using either complex step or finite difference, depending on whether the given function is complex-safe.

Here's an example of your code.  It doesn't perfectly replicate the dictionary which stores the user functions, but it's probably a bit easier to get their with this path, as opposed to reassigning compute.

```py
import openmdao.api as om

def MyReusableFunction(x, y): # <- The way I want it to work
    return x*y

connections = [('D2.F', 'D1.B')]

problem = om.Problem()

om.ExecComp.register('myfunc', MyReusableFunction, complex_safe=True)

D1 = om.ExecComp('C = myfunc(A, B)')
D2 = om.ExecComp('F = myfunc(D, E)')

problem.model.add_subsystem('D1', D1)
problem.model.add_subsystem('D2', D2)

for connection in connections:
    problem.model.connect(connection[0], connection[1])

problem.setup()

problem.run_model()
```

Let us know if this will not work for your use-case.